# useFetch data is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
const { response, setResponse } = useResponseState();

const handleNext = () => {
    if (
      response.currentResponse !== undefined &&
      response.responses!== undefined
    ) {
      if (response.currentResponse< response.responses.length) {
        setResponse({
          currentResponse: response.currentResponse + 1,
          responses: response.responses,
        });
      }
    }
  };

  const responseID= response.responses![response.currentResponse!].id ?? 0;
      const { data, error } = useFetch<ExampleType>(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT}example/${exampleID}`
      );

return error || !data ? (
    <>error</>
  ) : (
    <>success</>
```

Can anyone help me understand why when handleNext is called data is undefined. In the success part of the return there is a button with an onclick but I have tried to show only what you need to see. Can anyone see anything wrong here?

ResponseState is a context.

Endpoint returns something like:

```
{"id":1,"exampleProp2: "test"}
```

Hook:

```
import { useEffect, useReducer, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import State from './State';

type Cache<T> = { [url: string]: T };

// discriminated union type
type Action<T> =
  | { type: 'loading' }
  | { type: 'fetched'; payload: T }
  | { type: 'error'; payload: Error };

function useFetch<T = unknown>(url?: string, options?: RequestInit): State<T> {
  const cache = useRef<Cache<T>>({});

  // Used to prevent state update if the component is unmounted
  const cancelRequest = useRef<boolean>(false);

  const initialState: State<T> = {
    error: undefined,
    data: undefined,
  };

  // Keep state logic separated
  const fetchReducer = (state: State<T>, action: Action<T>): State<T> => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'loading':
        return { ...initialState };
      case 'fetched':
        return { ...initialState, data: action.payload };
      case 'error':
        return { ...initialState, error: action.payload };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(fetchReducer, initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Do nothing if the url is not given
    if (!url) return;

    const fetchData = async () => {
      dispatch({ type: 'loading' });

      // If a cache exists for this url, return it
      if (cache.current[url]) {
        dispatch({ type: 'fetched', payload: cache.current[url] });
        return;
      }

      try {
        const response = await fetch(url, options);
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(response.statusText);
        }

        const data = (await response.json()) as T;
        cache.current[url] = data;
        if (cancelRequest.current) return;

        dispatch({ type: 'fetched', payload: data });
      } catch (error) {
        if (cancelRequest.current) return;

        dispatch({ type: 'error', payload: error as Error });
      }
    };

    void fetchData();

    // Use the cleanup function for avoiding a possibly...
    // ...state update after the component was unmounted
    return () => {
      cancelRequest.current = true;
    };
  }, [url]);

  return state;
}

export default useFetch;
```

This is the exact hook used. Is there anything still not working here?

Comment: Post what is the endpoint is returning

Comment: Whats weird is if I force a re render by saving then it works and the success div loads..

Answer (score 1):

I depends on what's the API contract of `useFetch` are you calling (how the hook is working and what are the expected return values). But generally fetching is an asynchronous operation which is done on the background. The data can be really `undefined` or `null` at the first phase because the request has not been sent or response has not been received.

Let's say the hook returns the following stuff - `{ data, error, loading, requested }`. The return value could be following:

1. fetch not sent: `{ loading: false, requested: false }` *(that's not probable in your case)*
2. fetch sent, response not received: `{ loading: true, requested: true }`
3. success response received: `{ loading: false, requested: true, data: {} }`
4. failure response received: `{ loading: false, requested: true, error: {} }`

As you can can see, there is just one state in which the data are expected to be available. *This just a theoretical elaboration because you have not specified your `useFetch` hook enough.*

For example, you could be using the hook from [use-http](https://use-http.com/#/?id=basic-usage-auto-managed-state). If you check the documentation then you should notice that they suggest the initialize data by own value to avoid `undefined`. In your case, it would be something like this:

```js
  const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT}example/${exampleID}`
  const { data = {}, error, loading } = useFetch < ExampleType > (url);

  return loading ? (
    <>Loading...</>
  ) : error ? (
    <>Failure: ${JSON.stringify(error)}</>
  ) : (
    <>Success: ${JSON.stringify(data))</>
  )
```

You should definitely check the documentation of `useFetch<T>` which you are using it should be written here.

**Update for [custom hook](https://dev.to/techcheck/custom-react-hook-usefetch-eid)**

In case of the hook from [specified article](https://dev.to/techcheck/custom-react-hook-usefetch-eid), you should also consult the documentation for [axios response](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema). It clearly states that `data` are stored in so named attribute. It means that if you copied hook code as it is written article then it can't work. No part of the handler for `Promise.then` is using that value:

```js
//checking for multiple responses for more flexibility 
//with the url we send in.
res.data.content && setData(res.data.content);
res.content && setData(res.content);
```

It has to be fixed to access the response data correctly, for example:

```js
// Give up the flexibility
setData(rest.?data)
// Keep some flexibility
// ... but you have to define data acquisition algorithm
// const data = res.content || rest.data
// setData(data)
```

Comment: https://dev.to/techcheck/custom-react-hook-usefetch-eid

Comment: Just added a link to the useFetch I used

Comment: @Ben It looks like you have copied code from the website without even understanding what it does. This hook has many issues: incorrectly processes response from axios, changes value of loading from `null` to `"Loading..."` string and then to false. You should try to debug or use _console.log_ to see what's returning where and fix that hook first.

Comment: Actually realised that I linked the wrong article!! I have updated my post - any ideas?

Comment: @Ben It's relatively clean and tidy code but it still has issues. At first, I would recommend to add `loading: boolean` attribute to your state and set it to `true` in response to loading action and `false` to other actions. If you will `console.log` or debug watch it then you may get more concise view of what's going on. Also, it's unusual to replace the state using the initial `{ ...state, data: resp.data }` would be probably better.

Anyway, you forgot that `dispatch` is asynchronous and state can be in _loading_ phase. So, `error` & `data` can be undefined.

I will update answer ASAP.

Comment: Ahh I see so I need `return { ...initialState, loading: true };` and add loading to the state. Then can do `return error || !data || loading === true ? (
    <></>
  ) : ()`

Comment: also console.log'd loading, error and data in a useEffect but data is still constantly showing up undefined. I know the request is working because of the network tab.

Comment: I think its something to do with the useRef in the hook.. I am trying to call useFetch twice.. how can I overcome this?

Comment: @Ben I'm a little bit busy and tired at this moment (1 a.m. here). I see what your are trying to achieve but I'm not sure why it is failing. Could you check you compare your hook with this article ... https://rajeshnaroth.medium.com/managing-async-state-with-hooks-and-redux-8ab675ae6bdf ... I think you are both doing the same thing but you have just mixed "dispatch" into it.